# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 - Create Popup/Dialog

Tags: popup, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm currently trying to create a popup like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/faqQA.png

But i don't know where to start.
Is it a Webresource? If yes is it done via JScript or ASPX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck my article that describes creation of own dialog windows step-by-step - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2014/06/step-by-step-creating-dialog-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You would want an iFrame for this

Answer (score 0):

public IOrganizationService GetCRMService()
        {

```
        string Username = "**********";
        string password = "**********";
        IOrganizationService _service;
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
        credentials.UserName.Password = password;
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://*******.api.crm**.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

        Uri HomeRealm = null;


        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, HomeRealm, credentials, null);
        {

            _service = (IOrganizationService)proxy;

        }
        return _service;
    }<!---- Modal Gridvview popup for Dynamic crm -------!>protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IOrganizationService _service = GetCRMService();
        QueryExpression Query = new QueryExpression("contact");
        Query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
        filtering conditions
        Query.Criteria.AddCondition("fullname", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "xxx");
        Query.Criteria.AddCondition("emailaddress1", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "xxx");
        Query.Criteria.AddCondition("telephone1", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "xxx");
        Query.Criteria.AddCondition("address1_line2", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "xxx");
        EntityCollection collection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(Query);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("fullname");
        dt.Columns.Add("emailaddress1");
        dt.Columns.Add("telephone1");
        dt.Columns.Add("address1_line2");
        dt.Columns.Add("");

        foreach (Entity entity in collection.Entities)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["fullname"] = entity.Attributes["fullname"].ToString();
            dr["emailaddress1"] = entity.Attributes["emailaddress1"].ToString();
            dr["telephone1"] = entity.Attributes["telephone1"].ToString();
             dr["address1_line2"] = entity.Attributes["address1_line2"].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```